# How would I add timer to carousel sliders using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel sliders with text. I have my own custom js to those sliders. The carousel arrows are working fine but I want the sliders to move by itself after an interval.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="col-6 col-xs-12  " style="text-align:-webkit-center;">  

 <div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides w3-container w3-center w3-animate-right">
 <h2 class="font-size" id="f37" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="200ms">1</h2>

</div>

<div class="mySlides w3-container w3-center w3-animate-right">
 <h2 class="font-size" id="f37" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="200ms">2</h2>

</div>

<div class="mySlides w3-container w3-center w3-animate-right">
 <h2 class="font-size" id="f37" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="200ms">3</h2>

</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> 
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS

```
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

  function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

  function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
              }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            }
</script>
```

Hope I'm clear with the question. Ill highly appreciate your answer.
Ive updated the code to codepen and you can observe the weird behavior it has once I click on the arrows although the auto slides are working fine when idle.
https://codepen.io/mahirq8/pen/JjjJzbe

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `<h2 class="font-size" id="f37" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-interval="10000">1</h2>` instead of `data-delay=200ms`.

Comment: Thanks there. but nothing happened. anything else

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval()` or `setTimeout`?

Comment: What is `document.getElementsByClassName("dot")` referring to? There is nothing like that in your HTML...

Comment: Hi. Can you suggest me with the imlementation with my code.

Comment: See my answer... But what is `dot`? Your HTML does not have it?

Comment: I m not using the dots. just the arrows

Comment: Your code references "dot".... so you are using it. Or else, remove it from your question? It is confusing, because it generates errors if run like you posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `setTimeout` for that.

Add a variable `timer` at the top of your script:

```
var timer;
```

In your function `showSlides`, add the following two lines (anywhere, like at the end of it):

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(() => plusSlides(1), 2000);
```

If you now still use the arrow-buttons, the timer will reset and continue sliding the slides again 2 seconds after your last interference.

You can run it here:

```js
var timer;
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => plusSlides(1), 2000);
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <h1>111</h1>
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <h1>222</h1>
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <h1>333</h1>
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <h1>444</h1>
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <h1>555</h1>
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, ive used your code and implemented here at https://codepen.io/mahirq8/pen/JjjJzbe but no luck. The arrows are working fine but not the automate sliders

Comment: That is not the code I have but in my answer. There is no `var timer`, there is no `clearTimeout`... etc. Nothing corresponds to what I posted here.

Comment: Here is your original code (without "dot") and with the changes from my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/eL1og798/  Your link seems to have code from the other answer. It is not related to my answer at all.

Comment: you can see the updated code now at codepen. THe code is perfectly working fine thanks alot but if you observe that it is only showing me the odd once but not back to back slides.

Comment: What do you mean with "the odd once but not back to back slides"? It shows 111, then 222, then 333, then 111, then 222, ... etc, until you click, and then it changes to the direction you click, and then it continues from there again.

Comment: Your latest codepen is still having code from the other answer. Please.... please.. just take the code that I referred to. Don't mix it up!

Comment: can you have a look for a sec. Youll prolly get the idea https://codepen.io/mahirq8/pen/JjjJzbe

Comment: Sorry, but you are still referring to code from the other answer. For example, your code has `slideIndex++`. That is not coming from me. Will you PLEASE look at the code that I referred to? I have also included a snippet in my answer that you can run.

Comment: As you can see Ive added your code where you have told me to place it. Other than that, if i tend to remove the other peice of code its not working. I dont know to exactly what code do you want me to keep and delete it. Ill highly appreacite if you could place the script that you want me to have. Btw thank you for such a wonderful support by you

Comment: All the code is in my answer. Why don't you check it out? You added a mixture of both answers into your code. Just look in my answer? Did you run *that* code? Look at the code as you posted it in your question: I started from that. You seem to start from code that the other answer posted. It has `slideIndex++`, and it removed the argument `n` from the function, and did several other things. You have used *that* code to insert *my* code. That is not going to work. Just look at the snippet I posted, it has it all.

Comment: ok perfect. Its working. Thank you so very much. I know i was annoying but you carried me with a great support. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to the `<script>` tag.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

The one line you are missing is the last one
`setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);`

If you would like to see the direct code, you can use this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

Comment: Really appreciate your help there but that doesnt seems to be working.

Comment: you can use this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

Comment: Thank you. It is working perfectly with automatic slide change but the moment I have a carousel arrow button with the mentioned script on my question it does not work. I mean I want the arrow to function and the auto slider as well which I cant achieve.

Comment: Ive updated the question with the code on codepen. Have a look